# what meas this regex (.*\1)

Tags: regex, shell

i googled about regex for checking string more than twice in a line,
then i found this example:

egrep "(\w{2}).*\1" file

but i coudlnt understand "(\w{2}).*\1" this.

can someone explain me in detail or get me some reference web page??

Comment: Didn't know about that link. Good man, @rock321987.

Comment: i checked there but difficult to find what i want to actually i need to know .*\1 part but not in there

Comment: You need to use one of the many online regex testers: [`regex101.com`](http://regex101.com). Paste the regex and read the explanation on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `(\w{2})` matches any word character that includes all these: A-Z,
   a-z, 0-9 and underscore with a quantity of 2(`{2}` quantifier), it
   also groups them as a captured group i.e remembers the matched characters and those
   characters can be referenced again using numbered backreferences, in
   this case `\1`
2. `.*` matches 0 or more any chars
3. `\1` matches the 1st group again

**Therefore the regex tries to match any 2 word characters that are repeated after 0 or more characters in the same line.**

```
$ egrep "(\w{2}).*\1"
ab;;ab
ab;;ab
abcdab
abcdab
12ab12
12ab12
12abcd123
12abcd123
abab
abab
$
```

Inputs and matched output:

1. `ab;;ab`     captured group \1: `ab` and matched string is `ab;;ab`
2. `abcdab`     captured group \1: `ab` and matched string is `abcdab`
3. `12ab12`     captured group \1: `ab` and matched string is `12ab12`
4. `12abcd123`  captured group \1: `12` and matched string is
   `12abcd12`
5. `abab`       captured group \1: `ab` and matched string is `abab`

As pointed out more information on the meta/special characters can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Thanks a lot. i got it